# Null pointer exception when using Graphics in JFrame (Swing)

Tags: java, swing, exception, pointers, graphics

I am slowly learning java, and I have decided to try to build a tic tac toe game.  I dove off into trying to draw the board, and I found a simple method to draw lines that everyone said would work.  I have this so far:

```
    public void constructBoard() {
    JFrame frame = new JFrame("Tic Tac Toe");
    frame.setSize(600,600);
    frame.setVisible(true);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    frame.toFront();
    Graphics lines = new Graphics();
    lines = getGraphics();
    lines.drawLine(100,100,300,500);
    lines.setColor(Color.black);
  //  JLabel label = new JLabel ("Hello, World!", SwingConstants.CENTER);
  //  frame.add(label, BorderLayout.CENTER);
}
```

My JFrame comes up, my title is there, but no line.  I have tried multiple things, among which waw a separate method for the line, such as:

```
public void drawBoard(Graphics lines){
     lines = getGraphics();
     lines.drawLine(100,100,300,500);
     lines.setColor(Color.black);
}
```

But when I call this in my main class, it tells me I need something between the parentheses to match type Graphics.  My compiler (Eclipse) recommends null, but to me, that could be causing the null pointer exception.

I have the construct board method in a Board class, with a constructor Board() with super() inside it.

```
    public Board(){
        super();
    }
```

I then have a main class that just makes an object of type Board and calls my methods.  I have searched everywhere I know to look, and everywhere says what I have is the way to draw a line.  Then others with null pointer exceptions that I found either haven't gotten a solution, or haven't gotten one that works for me.  I have tried DebugGraphics, putting it all in the main class, and lines = new Graphics(); but that gives me an error.  Thanks for any help.

Full Board class:

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;



public class Board extends JPanel {
        public Board(){
            super();
        }
        public void constructBoard() {
            JFrame frame = new JFrame("Tic Tac Toe");
            frame.setSize(600,600);
            frame.setVisible(true);
            frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.toFront();
                Graphics lines = new Graphics();
                lines = getGraphics();
                lines.drawLine(100,100,300,500);
            lines.setColor(Color.black);
            //  JLabel label = new JLabel ("Hello, World!", SwingConstants.CENTER);
            //  frame.add(label, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        }
}
```

Full main class:

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;


public class Main {

    /**
     * @param args
     */
            public static void main(String[] args) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    Board board = new Board();
                    board.constructBoard();

            }

}
```

Comment: Hi - Try using "paintComponent ()": [Java2D: An Introduction and Tutorial](http://www.apl.jhu.edu/~hall/java/Java2D-Tutorial.html), or [Java graphics - paint and repaint](http://www.tech-recipes.com/rx/1177/java-graphics-paint-and-repaint/).

Comment: That looks like it would work if I knew how or could figure it out.  I just don't understand why the way I'm doing it won't work.  It's the most used way from what I can find, but everywhere I find people want the questioner to use something new and more complex as opposed to solving this problem.  Is there some reasoning behind that?

Comment: The trick is to not just "draw something", but to draw in *response* to a *(re)draw event*.  I was originally going to suggest an onPaint() handler, but the two first tutorials I found both used "paintComponent()" instead.  'Hope that helps .. PSM

Answer (score 0):

I think you started in a wrong way. Please see below a proof of concept showing you how to actually override the `paintComponent` method of a `JPanel` in order to be able to display custom drawn graphical stuff inside it. That is the place where you would have to draw the board.

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class App {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Test");
        frame.getContentPane().add(new MainPanel());
        frame.setBounds(100, 100, 600, 400);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}

class MainPanel extends JPanel {
    MainPanel() {
    }

    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        g.setColor(Color.BLUE);
        int width = getWidth();
        int height = getHeight();
        drawBoard((Graphics2D) g, width, height);
    }

    private void drawBoard(Graphics2D g2, int width, int height) {
        // TODO: this is the place where you actually want to draw your board
        g2.drawRect(10, 10, width - 20, height - 20);
    }
}
```